# C# Create one Label filled with 2d string array

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, maze

Im doing a c# maze that should fill up the screen like

```
x x x x x x
x x       x
x x x x x x
x x  x x x x
x  x x x x x
x x x x  x x
   x x x x x
x    
x x x x x x
```

The x's are places randomly and the mouse is trying to find its way out. What I am having trouble with is finding a way to fill something up with x's. I tried creating a 2D string array full of x's and fill a label, but no luck.

What is the best way of doing this? Using a panel or maybe something I don't know about?
I have to do this in WFA

Comment: What do you use for displaying it? WPF/Winforms?

Comment: I can only recommend for now to not use a label as game surface.

Comment: I used WPF. What could I use then?

Comment: A Canvas for example. There are multiple options. In a Canvas you would be able to draw whatever you like. http://wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html

Comment: use a console application for this

Comment: You said you are new to C# then WPF can be a bit overwhelming for you. But you can try.

Comment: im supposed to use wpf for this

Comment: you said you tried to create a 2d string array. was this successful. also a console app would allow to focus on the concept and logic of the maze then when your done you can worry about the graphics of wpf. wpf will bloat your small project alot and you will end up wasting a lot of time with it and not making a mouse maze game

Comment: the string array would only print one X in my entire label ` for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
           {
                gridmaze.Text = positions[i, j];
            }
        } `

Comment: I think you should separate the game map as a data structure and the display of it. Your data map would probably be a 2D array indeed and you could paint e.g. it on a canvas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same example as my other answer but with Windows Forms :) Its nearly the same.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      var blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
      for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
      {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
          e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(x*20, y*20), new Point(x*20 + 10, y*20+10));
          e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(x*20, y*20+10), new Point(x*20 + 10, y*20));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You have to add a Panel into your window (name it panel1 if it isn't yet) and an event handler for `Paint`

Nothing complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To give you a quickstart with drawing in WPF I created a little example for you which directly draws X's into the window.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
      base.OnRender(dc);
      var whitePen = new Pen();
      whitePen.Brush = Brushes.White;
      for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
      {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
          dc.DrawLine(whitePen, new Point(x*20, y*20), new Point(x*20 + 10, y*20+10));
          dc.DrawLine(whitePen, new Point(x*20, y*20+10), new Point(x*20 + 10, y*20));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can add your condition like `if (positions[x, y] == 1)` around the DrawLine calls to prevent a specific X from being drawn.

[image]

Comment: im so sorry I meant I have to do it in Windows Form Application

Comment: It's a bit similar there you would override OnPaint().

Comment: im sorry but I don't understand it, its more complicated then I have to make it. Im supposed to use a 2d array to fill up something. I don't know what that something is supposed to be

Comment: My code shows you how to fill the window. Use your array to decide which X to draw. I added another example in Window Forms if that seems too complicated to you.

Answer (score -1):

After generating the random map and saving it on the 2d array, cycle trought every cell of the map (adding it to the label) and add a new line everytime it reaches the end of the row.

Also, what happened when you tried to fill the label with the 2d array map?

Comment: Sorry im new to C# what is map? I used for loop to assign every position in my array to "X" but it would only print out one in my Label

Comment: Maybe you did it like this - "labelName.Text = array[x, y]",
but you have to do it like this - "labelName.Text += array[x, y]".